# Selenium returning NoSuchElementException but the element exists

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having this code

```
driver.implicitly_wait(300) # I have tried different timers
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@aria-pressed='false'])[1]").click()
```

But I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//button[@aria-pressed='false'])[1]"}
```

However, this exists in my HTML content, like:

```
<div class="webix_el_box" style="width:90px; height:26px">
    <button aria-pressed="false" type="button" class="webix_img_btn" style="line-height:22px;">
        <span class="webix_icon_btn fa-lock red" style="max-width:22px;">
        </span> Read Only
    </button>
</div>
```

I have also tried to use the XPath expression:

```
//button[@class='webix_img_btn']//child::span[@class='webix_icon_btn fa-lock red']
```

Both XPath expressions worked fine in Google Chrome.
In the website I am able to find the button using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and 'Read Only', can I use it in Selenium?

---

It is not working because of *[Selenium Driver is one page behind ajax call after large json data download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055456/selenium-driver-is-one-page-behind-ajax-call-after-large-json-data-download)*.

Comment: Edit: there are 3 of these buttons of almost same content, need to select three as per requirement and that is why [1] in my XPATH

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **Read Only** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.webix_el_box > button.webix_img_btn"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='webix_el_box']/button[@class='webix_img_btn' and contains(., 'Read Only')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- ["selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element" while clicking a 'Next' button with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [Selenium in Python: "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, thank you so much for your reply. I get a timeout even during that time. For example when I try using XPath. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='webix_el_box']/button[@class='webix_img_btn' and contains(., 'Read Only')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\jrex\PycharmProjects\Dragon\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I figured out what the issue is. I came to this page after clicking a button in another page. There is no change in URL, but I did print(driver.page_source) and it is still printing data from previous page. Not sure how to load this page. If you have any idea, please help.

Comment: Hi, I think it not working all because of this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055456/selenium-driver-is-one-page-behind-ajax-call-after-large-json-data-download

Answer (score 0):

Try doing just

```
driver.implicitly_wait(300)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-pressed='false']").click()
```

This will click on the first element that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: There are 3 of those XPATH in my HTML and I need to click the 1st one
I tried it anyway 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-pressed='false']"}